# Reading xls file from MapReduce Program

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I need to read a XLS file which is saved on a Hadoop Cluster. I need to parse the file using JAVA's MapReduce Programming model. 
Please help me in this regard.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I believe you have two options:

- Write your own custom `InputFormat` that can read an Excel file
- Generate a CSV or TSV file from the spreadsheet and use `TextInputFormat`

Comment: Could you shed some light on how to make custom InputFormat to read Excel File.

Comment: If it were me, I would jump on the CSV/TSV approach. If that isn't an option, you would probably have to use [POI](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/index.html) to read Excel within a custom [InputFormat](http://developer.yahoo.com/hadoop/tutorial/module5.html#inputformat). I have never done this though, so I am only guessing.